# GWT upgrade from 2.1 to 2.4

Tags: gwt

while compiling from GWT 2.1 to 2.4, the following error is shown:

Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected

so kindly provide me with the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There's a binary backwards-incompatibility in GWT 2.2 (where `com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType` et al. were changed from classes to interfaces).   You have to update your third-party dependencies with ones that have been compiled against the GWT 2.2 SDK or a newer version; for your own library or if the third-party lib has been somewhat *abandoned*, you'll have to recompile it (`javac`).

[GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) for example provides 2 builds of its 1.5 release: one compatible with GWT 2.1.1 and older, and one compatible with 2.2 onwards (there are two distinct JARs in the `gwt-1.5.zip` download).